# Некорректные вертикальные отступы у вложенных списков

Tags: дефект, дизайн, markdown, список

При выводе вложенных списков имеет место ошибка вёрстки.

Рассмотрим проблему на примере фрагмента [конкретного сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/89697/208074):

> [image: Экранный снимок]

Обратите внимание:

1. Между *элементом списка первого уровня* и *первым элементом списка второго уровня* имеется отступ **где-то на миллиметр больше межабзацного отступа**.
2. Между *последним элементом списка второго уровня* и *продолжением элемента первого уровня* **отступ отсутствует вообще**.
3. Если же после *последнего элемента списка второго уровня* вставить *новый элемент списка первого уровня*, отступ имеет нормальную величину.

Comment: Проблема, в принципе, решается путём [добавления одного пробела](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/89697/5).

Comment: @alexolut, не спорю, можно и так. Но это скорее хак с занесением абзаца (`p`) внутрь списка (`ul`). Из-за этого, кстати, у абзаца помимо вертикального отступа **[появился ещё и горизонтальный](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Oeu.png)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задал [вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287903/339911) на англоязычной Мете. Оказалось попытки сделать подобное уже были, но *markdown* просто имеет свои ограничения и в данном случае приходится прибегать к довольно сложному [обвесу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286428/339911).

Любопытно заметить, что в android-приложении *Stack Exchange* такие списки рисуются с правильным выравниванием.

Оказывается, что внешний вид списков может быть улучшен путём изменения CSS. Соответствующее [предложение](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287967/339911) есть на Meta.SE.

Comment: То есть *занулять `padding-top` (был `0.5em`) и выставлять `margin-bottom` в `1em`* в `ul` и `ol` для исправления ошибки они не будут?