# Давайте сохраним страницы справки актуальными!

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, закрытие-вопросов

Хотя инициатива завершена, пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь вносить правки, если вы хотите что–то улучшить. Я получу уведомления и обновлю публикацию в справочном центре.

---

В начале этой недели мои коллеги внесли несколько улучшений в диалоги закрытия вопросов и обновили справочный центр, чтобы он соответствовал новому интерфейсу.

Давайте вместе обновим страницы справки на нашем сайте и добавим правильные переводы новых строк!

- [Список добавленных строк в интерфейс сайта на Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yaL9EWFUmSZIdqXeydAG3yh5W6kthqSv4QHiS-ei7ns/edit). Пожалуйста, добавляйте ваши предложения переводов на [Traducir.win](https://traducir.win/). Обратите внимание, что хотя некоторые строки на английском языке поменялись, нам следует использовать наши старые. Например, причины закрытия вопросов.
- Изменения в справке были на трёх страницах:

  - «[Flag posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)» («[Отмечать тревогой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10368/6)»)
  - «[Cast close and reopen votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)» («[Закрывать и переоткрывать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10367/6)»)
  - «[What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)» («[Что означает статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»? Почему некоторые вопросы «требуют правки»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10366/6)»)

  Давайте попробуем обновить и их тоже! Ниже, в ответах к этому вопросу, я добавил текущие версии каждой из страниц. Ответы отмечены как общие. Пожалуйста, если вы видите расхождения или возможность для улучшения, просто внести правку в ответ. Как только мы определимся с итоговой версией, я обновлю страницы в справочном центре.

Если у вас есть любые вопросы, пожалуйста, задайте их в виде комментария к этому сообщению. Спасибо! =)

Comment: Заметил, что исчез статус "Требует правки", а вопросы, забракованные в очереди проверок, сразу становятся "закрытыми". Это связано с этими изменениями? Кроме того, если вопрос закрыт с причиной "не по теме", то конкретная причина больше не отображается. Или отображается только автору?

Comment: А я вот заметил [кривое форматирование списков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4177/176217), которое никак не хотят фиксить.

Answer (score 3):

## [Отмечать тревогой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

#### Что такое сигнал тревоги?

Сигнал тревоги – это способ привлечь внимание сообщества к содержимому, которое не соответствует правилам или тематике сайта. Используйте сигнал тревоги если:

1. Необходимо внимание модератора ♦.
2. [Ответ не является ответом](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/81389/flagging-as-not-an-answer#81392) (включая ответы-ссылки).
3. Сообщение очень низкого качества (то есть [никакая улучшающая правка не спасет сообщение](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/)).
4. Не соответствует тематике сайта, [не являтеся вопросом](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question), [слишком специфичный](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized), не конструктивный, повтор вопроса.
5. Спам (например, [реклама](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work))
6. Оскорбительный, агрессивный или сообщение содержит приступы изливания ненависти.

Если, отмечая тревожное сообщение, вы запутаетесь, какую из причин выбрать, воспользуйтесь ссылками выше.

#### Когда следует отмечать сообщение тревогой?

Если вы видите на сайте содержимое, из-за которого вам некомфортно или вы считаете, что оно неуместно, *пожалуйста*, отметить сообщение тревогой для того, чтобы привлечь к нему внимание.

#### Как отмечать сообщения тревогой?

Если нажать на ссылку `тревога`, расположенную под сообщением, вы увидите всплывающее диалоговое окно как на изображении:

[image: Flag dialog]

#### Что произойдет, если я отмечу сообщение тревогой, как *спам* или *оскорбительные*?

Такие отметки специально предусмотрены для того, чтобы, благодаря сообществу, быстро удалять оскорбительные сообщения.

- 3 сигнала тревоги - сообщение удаляется с главной страницы.
- 6 сигналов тревоги - сообщение блокируется и удаляется, его автор теряет 100 баллов репутации.

Участники с привилегией «[инструменты модератора](/help/privileges/moderator-tools)» видят оскорбительные сигналы тревоги для сообщений и могут отреагировать соответствующе.

#### Что произойдет, если я отмечу тревогой сообщение, как «требует внимания модератора ♦»?

Вам будет необходимо ясно изложить суть проблемы. Сообщения с тревогами для модератора рассматриваются в приоритетном порядке, они попадают в особую очередь и видны всем модераторам (кроме участников с привилегией Инструменты модератора). К сигналам тревоги для модератора мы относимся очень серьезно, и, будьте уверены, доводим дело до конца.

#### Можно ли отменить сигнал тревоги?

Часто в этом нет необходимости, потому что сигнал тревоги с обоснованием  «содержит оскорбления или спам» действителен только на протяжении 48 часов, если только количество тревожных отметок не превысит допустимый максимум.

Если вы снимете свой сигнал тревоги об оскорблениях или спаме, то общее количество сигналов тревоги уменьшится к прежнему значению. Это позволит автору сообщения (или кому-нибудь еще с правом редактирования) вернуть сообщение, которое кто-то ранее счел оскорбительным, на место. Отменять сигнал тревоги могут только участники имеющие необходимые для этого привилегии.

#### Сколько сообщений я могу ответить тревогой?

Изначально вы можете отметить тревогой **10** сообщений в день. Количество может возрасти до **100**:

- Вы получаете один дополнительный сигнал за каждые 2000 баллов репутации.
- Вы получаете дополнительные сигналы тревоги в случае если голосуете корректно.

Answer (score 2):

## [Что означает статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»? Почему некоторые вопросы «требуют правки»?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

#### Почему некоторые вопросы «требуют правки»?

Вопросы, [не соответствующие тематике сайта](/help/on-topic) или критериям качества, могут быть отмечены как «требующие правки» опытными участниками сообщества. На вопрос «требующий правки» нельзя опубликовать ответ, но можно внести улучшающую правку, чтобы в дальнейшем открыть его повторно.

Вопрос автоматически попадает в очередь на повторное открытие, если он был изменён в течение пяти дней с момента получения статуса «требующий правки». Если вопрос не был открыт повторно в течение пяти дней, его статус изменяется с `[требует правки]` на `[закрыт]`.

Каждый закрытый или требующий правки вопрос сопровождается пояснением, которое помогает автору (и другим участникам сообщества) понять, что именно следует сделать для того, чтобы вопрос был открыт повторно.

Причины закрытия вопросов.

- **[дубликат](/help/duplicates)** — основной целью закрытия является сбор всей информации, относящейся к вопросу, в одном месте.

  > Такой вопрос задавали ранее и на него уже получен ответ. Если представленные ответы не являются исчерпывающими, пожалуйста, отредактируйте этот вопрос, пояснив, в чём состоит его отличие, или задайте новый вопрос.
- **[не по теме](/help/on-topic)** — каждое сообщество само решает, какие вопросы допустимы, а какие — нет.

  > Скорее всего, данный вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта.

  Воспользуйтесь правкой, если вы можете переписать вопрос так, чтобы он соответствовал тематике сайта.
- **непонятна суть вопроса** — иногда сообществу требуется больше информации, чтобы помочь вам в решении вашей проблемы.

  > Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

  Отредактируйте ваш вопрос, чтобы он как можно более конкретно описывал то, что вы пытаетесь решить. Пожалуйста, не забудьте ответить на все комментарии, оставленные другими участниками.
- **вопрос слишком общий** — если для ответа на ваш вопрос требуется написать целую книгу или существует множество верных ответов, он, скорее всего, не соответствует формату вопросов и ответов.

  > В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.
- **необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать однозначно верный ответ** — [обсуждения, основанные на различных мнениях](/help/dont-ask) — это прекрасно, но они тоже с большой вероятностью не подходят для формата вопросов и ответов.

  > Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

#### Кто может отметить вопрос как «требующий правки»?

В день, участники с репутацией $ReputationRequiredToClose и более могут голосовать до $CloseVotesPerDay раз за закрытие вопросов. Если вопрос получает $CloseVotesNeededForClosure голосов за закрытие, его статус изменяется на `[требует правки]`. Эти же участники могут проголосовать за повторное открытие вопроса таким же способом. Каждый участник может отдать всего один голос за закрытие или повторное открытие одного вопроса. (Например, если вы проголосовали за закрытие вопроса, который затем был закрыт, а после повторно открыт, вы не сможете ещё раз проголосовать за его закрытие).

Модераторы могут закрывать и открывать вопросы без голосования.

Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с разделом [«Что делать, если я не согласен с закрытием вопроса? Как его снова открыть?»](/help/reopen-questions) для получения подробной информации о повторном открытии вопросов.

#### Почему часть вопросов помечена как «закрытые»?

Автор вопроса, отмеченного как `[требующего правки]`, имеет возможность внести улучшающую правку в течение пяти дней. Если вопрос, отмеченный как `[требующий правки]`, будет улучшен автором, он автоматически попадет в [очередь проверок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4912), в которой он может быть открыт повторно. Если вопрос не был открыт повторно в течение пяти дней, состояние `[требует правки]` автоматически изменяется на `[закрыт]`. Функциональной разницы между состояниями `[требует правки]` и `[закрыт]` нет; в обоих состояниях на вопрос нельзя дать ответ, но можно комментировать, голосовать и редактировать.

Answer (score 2):

## [Закрывать и переоткрывать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

#### Что такое закрытие вопроса?

Закрытие – это демократический процесс, посредством которого сообщество голосованием выявляет вопросы не соответствующие тематике сайта, плохо сформулированные вопросы или уже заданные вопросы.

#### В каких случаях стоит голосовать за закрытие вопроса?

Вопросы следует закрывать если:

- они схожи с ранее заданными вопросами, и ответы на них, скорее всего, будут идентичными;
- они неясно сформулированы, слишком размыты или не понятно, в чем именно заключается вопрос;
- согласно [правилам](/help/on-topic), вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта.

Обратите внимание, что после того, как ваша репутация достигла уровня, когда вы можете голосовать за закрытие, вам больше не нужно отмечать вопрос тревогой, чтобы привлечь внимание модератора, который бы закрыл или переместил вопрос. Теперь ответственность за голосование лежит на вас.

Смотрите также: [Что изменится в сигналах тревоги после того, как я смогу голосовать за закрытие?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3154/how-should-my-flagging-change-when-i-gain-the-ability-to-vote-to-close)

#### Как проголосовать за закрытие вопроса?

Количество уже отданных голосов за закрытие конкретного вопроса будет отражаться под телом вопроса в круглых скобках рядом с соответствующей ссылкой следующим образом:

```
закрыть (3)
```

Если голосов за закрытие еще нет, ссылка будет выглядеть так:

```
закрыть
```

Чтобы проголосовать за закрытие вопроса или просмотреть, как проголосовали другие участники – нажмите на ссылку «закрыть» под телом вопроса. Вы увидите список причин для закрытия с их описанием, а также количество отданных за них голосов.

[image: Диалог закрытия вопроса]

Если вы хотите проголосовать за какую–либо причину, то поставьте галку напротив её описания, затем нажмите кнопку «Закрыть». Если вы отметили, что вопрос «не по теме», вам необходимо пояснить, в чём конкретно заключается несоответствие, выбрав соответствующий пункт в дополнительном меню.

Чтобы вопрос был закрыт, необходимо, чтобы 5 участников проголосовало за закрытие, за исключением, когда вопрос закрывается как дубликат – в этом случае вопрос будет закрыт, как только за закрытие проголосует хотя бы один участник с золотым знаком по любой из меток вопроса.

В течение суток вы можете отдать 24 голоса за закрытие.

Если за 4 дня не набралось необходимого количество голосов за закрытие вопроса, то все отданные голоса считаются устаревшими и вопрос остается открытым. Каждый новый голос за закрытие запускает отсчет заново. Более того, [если вопрос не набрал 100 просмотров, то отсчет не запускается вовсе](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today/97594#97594).

#### Что происходит, когда вопрос закрывается?

После закрытия вопроса новые ответы к нему не принимаются, а к заголовку добавляется статусная строка `[требует правки]`. Через 5 дней, если вопрос не будет открыт повторно, статус изменится на `[закрыто]`. Закрытые вопросы можно открыть повторно, путем голосования. Текущее количество голосов за повторное открытие отображается под телом вопросом в круглых скобках:

```
переоткрыть (3)
```

Число голосов, которые вопрос должен набрать для переоткрытия, будет указано во всплывающей подсказке. Если никто не проголосовал за повторное открытие вопроса, то ссылка будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
переоткрыть
```

Хотя вопрос может пройти несколько циклов закрытия и повторного открытия, каждый участник может участвовать в голосовании не более одного раза. Если вопрос был закрыт, его можно объединить с другим, переместить на другой сайт нашей сети или даже удалить.

#### Альтернатива закрытию вопроса

Если вам не хватает репутации, чтобы проголосовать за закрытие, или вы уже использовали все голоса за текущий день, вы можете поступить иначе.

- Если вопрос является дубликатом, добавьте комментарий со ссылкой на аналогичный вопрос.
- Если содержание вопроса совершенно неприемлемо (например, вопрос содержит спам или оскорбления), [отметьте его тревогой](/help/privileges/flag-posts).

#### Просмотр голосов за закрытие или повторное открытие вопроса

Эта привилегия позволяет просматривать две специальные очереди: одна с вопросами, которые, вероятно, следует [закрыть](/review/close), другая с теми, которые следует [открыть повторно](/review/reopen).

Каждый вопрос, получивший голос за закрытие или отмеченный сигналом тревоги, появится в «очереди на закрытие». Если вопрос попал в этот список, участники могут голосовать за его закрытие, редактировать вопрос или рекомендовать оставить «как есть». Правки или необходимое количество голосов с рецензией «оставить открытым» снимут вопрос с рассмотрения и немедленно запустят таймер «срока давности» голосования за его закрытие. Если после остановки голосования вопрос получает еще один закрывающий голос, то он будет повторно поставлен в очередь на закрытие. Вопрос получивший голос за закрытие как дубликат, также попадет в список вопросов–дубликатов. Для удобства просмотра список спрятан во вкладке наверху.

Аналогичным образом в очереди на повторное открытие будут появляться те вопросы, голосование по которым открыто в данный момент. Участники могут голосовать за повторное открытие вопросов, редактировать их или оставлять вопросы закрытыми. Набрав необходимо количество голосов «оставить закрытым», вопрос пропадает из очереди на переоткрытие. Система автоматически отправляет вопросы отредактированные в течении 5 дней после закрытия в очередь на повторное открытие. У вопросов, которые вы уже просмотрели, наверху появится дополнительная панель, чтобы их было лучше видно. Таким же образом вопросы, отмеченные как дубликаты, будут появляться в списке дубликатов, расположенном во вкладке наверху.