# Переписываем страницу справки про закрытие вопросов!

Tags: дефект, справка, закрытие-вопросов

Так как справка давно не обновлялась, на мете [идёт сбор всех дефектов справки в одном месте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12602/). Некоторые страницы справки устарели и нуждаются в серьёзной корректировке. Одна из таких статьей справки — [Что означает статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»? Почему некоторые вопросы «требуют правки»?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Здесь я предлагаю переписать эту страницу справки, чтобы потом сотруднику осталось лишь скопировать её.

Старая версия статьи есть [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10366/532877) и пока что в самой справке, новая - в общем ответе на этот пост.

Какая информация конкретно устарела:

- Вся информация про статус вопроса [требует правки] — чуть ли не половина статьи об этом.
- Изменились названия и подробные описания причин закрытий:

  - вопрос слишком общий -> необходимо конкретизировать + изменилось подробное описание приичины закрытия.
  - необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать однозначно верный ответ -> Невозможно дать объективный ответ + изменилось подробное описание причины
  - непонятна суть вопроса -> изменилось описание причины закрытия.
- Есть мелкие дефекты. Например:

> Причины закрытия вопросов.
>
> - первая
> - вторая
> - и т.д....

После "причины закрытия вопросов" либо должно быть двоеточие, а не точка, либо это вообще должен быть заголовок.

**P.S:** Так как ответ на этот пост будет сделан общим, то для того, чтобы его отредактировать, нужно всего 100 баллов репутации. Пожалуйста, помогите улучшить новую версию статьи!

Comment: Интересно, какой же сотрудник будет это копировать, though...

Comment: Угу, я об этом же подумал. Прежде чем вкладывать усилия в переписывание, нужно убедиться, что кто-то из сотрудников имеет желание и возможность это публиковать. Предложения по переписыванию справки часто игнорировались и во времена Николаса.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight у сотрудников есть возможность редактировать справку. Можно будет попросить модераторов позвать сотрудника  (т.к. у них какие-то закрытые чаты есть, через эти чаты они звали сотрудника, чтобы тот помог организовать выборы), либо сделать это самим, например через форму обратной связи. Насчёт желания - во-первых на то они и сотрудники, а во-вторых - сотруднику-то нужно лишь скопировать.

Answer (score 1):

## Что означает статус вопроса [закрыт]? Почему некоторые вопросы закрывают?

#### Почему некоторые вопросы закрывают?

Вопросы, [не соответствующие тематике сайта](/help/on-topic) или критериям качества, могут быть отмечены как закрытые опытными участниками сообщества. На закрытый вопрос нельзя опубликовать ответ, но можно комментировать, голосовать или внести улучшающую правку, чтобы в дальнейшем открыть его повторно.

Каждый закрытый вопрос сопровождается пояснением, которое помогает автору (и другим участникам сообщества) понять, что именно следует сделать для того, чтобы вопрос был открыт повторно.

#### Причины закрытия вопросов

- **[Дубликат](/help/duplicates)** — основной целью закрытия является сбор всей информации, относящейся к вопросу, в одном месте.

> Такой вопрос задавали ранее и на него уже получен ответ. Если представленные ответы не являются исчерпывающими, пожалуйста, отредактируйте этот вопрос, пояснив, в чём состоит его отличие, или задайте новый вопрос.

- **[Не по теме](/help/on-topic)** — каждое сообщество само решает, какие вопросы допустимы, а какие — нет.

> Этот вопрос не соответствует требованиям сайта «Stack Overflow на русском».

Воспользуйтесь правкой, если вы можете переписать вопрос так, чтобы он соответствовал тематике и требованиям сайта.

- **Непонятна суть вопроса** — иногда сообществу требуется больше информации, чтобы помочь вам в решении вашей проблемы.

> Этот вопрос необходимо уточнить или дополнить подробностями.

Отредактируйте ваш вопрос, чтобы он как можно более конкретно описывал то, что вы пытаетесь решить. Пожалуйста, не забудьте ответить на все комментарии, оставленные другими участниками.

- **Необходимо конкретизировать** — если для ответа на ваш вопрос требуется написать целую книгу, он, скорее всего, не соответствует формату вопросов и ответов.

> Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

- **Невозможно дать объективный ответ** — обсуждения, основанные на различных мнениях — это прекрасно, но они тоже с большой вероятностью не подходят для формата вопросов и ответов.

> Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

#### Кто может закрыть вопрос?

Участники с репутацией 3000 и более могут голосовать до 50 раз в день за закрытие вопросов. Для того, чтобы закрыть вопрос, нужно 5 голосов за закрытие. Эти же участники могут проголосовать за повторное открытие вопроса таким же способом. Каждый участник может отдать всего один голос за закрытие или повторное открытие одного вопроса. (Например, если вы проголосовали за закрытие вопроса, который затем был закрыт, а после повторно открыт, вы не сможете ещё раз проголосовать за его закрытие).

Модераторы могут закрывать и открывать вопросы без голосования.

Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с разделом [«Что делать, если я не согласен с закрытием вопроса? Как его снова открыть?»](/help/reopen-questions) для получения подробной информации о повторном открытии вопросов.

Comment: А для чего иметь отдельно версию markdown? Всё необходимое ведь можно получить через кнопку редактирования.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ убрал.

Comment: Не просто "до 50 раз", а "до 50 раз в день". А то можно случайно подумать, что участник за всю жизнь может только 50 раз проголосовать за закрытие) И почему-то нет последнего абзаца ("Почему часть вопросов помечена как «закрытые»?")

Comment: @Глеб там было *"**В день**, участники с репутацией 3000 и более могут голосовать до 50 раз за закрытие вопросов."*, но я согласен, что сформулировано было непонятно, исправил на *"Участники с репутацией 3000 и более могут голосовать до 50 раз в день за закрытие вопросов."*.

Comment: @Глеб то, что последнего абзаца нет - это [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано]: там же про отличие "требует правки" (упразднённый статус) от "закрыт" (сейчас он только и остался).